# .htaccess redirect subdirectory to subdirectory without changing URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is The senario
http://example.com/it

If I click: /it redirect to /it2 without changing URL.

if I click /it2 show content of itself (it2) but the URL change to /it

I tried this but this code change the URL:

```
RewriteRule ^it$ /it3 [L,NC,QSA,R]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+it2[/?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^it2(/.*)?$ /it$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^it(/.*)?$ /it2$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: tnx but not happen anything...I am on localhost...but I sure mode_rewrite is enable...I already redirect a  code like this:  **RewriteRule ^(archives\.html)/([0-9-]+)/?$ /$1/?option=com_bahaedini&date=$2 [L,NC,QSA,R]**

Comment: yes and  The main url in destination is:option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&Itemid=1137

Comment: tried this..but no success: RewriteRule ^(it\.html)/?$ /$1/?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&Itemid=1137 [L,NC,QSA,R]

Comment: Joomla doen't like internal rewrites. That 301 rule you can place at top and it will work.

Comment: I don't underestant your mean

Answer (score 0):

Update your index.htm in /it

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.example.com/it2">
```